# What do ethics have to do with transplantation?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In [research*eu No.62 Feb 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar99H.jpg) it is written:

> However, there is the risk that these advances [in organ transplantation] will cause us to cross the only barrier that we most certainly do not want to cross: that of ethics.

What does author refer to by saying "that(barrier) of ethics" at the end of the passage?

Comment: Hello Jack. It seems that you understand the English here, but are not clear on the ethics.  I don't think you need to be an English speaker to understand that inter-species organ transplantation has an ethical aspect.  But discussing that ethical aspect is off topic. The first question might be answerable here.  The second is not.

Comment: If you can, please link to the image and type the words.  It is not good to have images of text.  But it is good to have the source of the text.  So please link to the page which contains the image, rather than posting the image itself

Answer (score 2):

"Barrier" is a metaphor.  Ethics (the moral principles that govern a person's behaviour or the conducting of an activity) stops us from doing things that are wrong.  There are moral principles surrounding organ transplant (I'm not going to explain these here)

If you "break the ethical barrier" or "cross the ethical line" it means you do something that is morally wrong.